# Calling singleton class throw EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, singleton, exc-bad-access

There is a strange behavior in my code and I really don't know how to solve it.
I have a Singleton class with this definition:

**AppModelLocator.h>**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppModelManager : NSObject

+ (AppModelManager *)sharedManager;

@end
```

**AppModelLocator.m**

```
#import "AppModelManager.h"

static AppModelManager *instance = nil;

@implementation AppModelManager

#pragma mark - Singletone
#pragma mark

+ (AppModelManager *)sharedManager
{
    @synchronized ([AppModelManager class]) {
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [AppModelManager new];
        }
    }

    return instance;
}

+ (id)alloc
{
    @synchronized ([AppModelManager class]) {
        NSAssert(instance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate the second instance of AppModelManager.");
        instance = [super alloc];
        return instance;
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

When I call `[AppModelLocator sharedManager]`somewhere in my code everything is fine. But when I call the singleton class after a specific line of code it throws me EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffeec) and refers to `return instance` in `sharedManager` definition in the singleton class.

That specific code is initializing a class that create a HTTP request and start sending the request but in the class is not any reference of `AppModelLocator` or something special. It is a simple creating of `NSURLConnection` and its delegate methods.

I used similar classes and approach in other applications and they are working fine and I wonder what is wrong with this class. I tried a dozen other ways of creating singleton class but none of them were useful.

Comment: You haven't overridden `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` - are you releasing your singleton somewhere in your app (This is only a valid comment if you're not using ARC :)

Comment: PS If you _are_ using ARC, this link http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html will give you a much better way to do them :)

Comment: I'm using ARC so there is no need to override `retain`, `release` and `autorelease`. Also I tested the method described in the link. No change in the result.

Comment: What's the specific line of code that precedes this exception? If you've tried all these things then it's probably not accessing your singleton that's the problem :)

Comment: It's the way of calling: `AppModelManager *m = [AppModelManager sharedManager];` that throws the exception and it's the precedes lines: `KeyExchangeRequest *request = [[KeyExchangeRequest alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"keyexchange" delegate:self options:options]; [request start];`

Comment: Is `KeyExchangeRequest` being released by ARC early? If you're calling start but aren't keeping `request` around ARC will think you're finished with it - try making it a property on your class and see if the crash goes away?

Comment: If I call the singleton in the delegate of request, when the result comes, the exception would be thrown too. I think something is wrong in the threads or in setting `instance` and keeping the value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12705/discussion-between-emad-and-deanwombourne)

Comment: I'm using Swift (in Xcode 11.2) and I got the same error when accessing a singleton. I tried a lot of options without success. Finally I quit and reopened Xcode and it worked. Apple should really work in improving error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what was wrong in the code. I made a `NSURL` instance dynamically and I used 3rd library to encrypt the URL. Something through the encoding caused the crash in special condition but I wonder why the exception raised after calling the singleton class. Anyway the issue was not because of the singleton definition as deanWombourne said.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use GCD to instantiate your singleton?

```
+ (AppModelManager *)sharedManager
{
    static AppModelManager* instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[AppModelManager alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Read the comments first ;) It's not the singleton that's causing the crash.